# error with django collectstatic

Tags: python, django

I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04) for setting up Django with Nginx and Gunicorn. One of the main components is the collecstatic command.

This is the code I used:

```
~/myprojectdir/manage.py collectstatic
```

and I replaced "myprojectdir" with the actual directory.

First I received this error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.
```

And so I changed a line in settings.py from

```
STATICFILES_DIR = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
```

to

```
STATIC_ROOT = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')]
```

However after that change, I now get this error:

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list
```

Could someone explain what this means and how to fix it? Thank you so much!

Comment: This question does not match what this site is about. Code Review is about improving existing, working code. Code Review is not the site to ask for help in fixing or changing *what* your code does. Once the code does what you want, we would love to help you do the same thing in a cleaner way! Please see our [help center](/help/on-topic) for more information.

Comment: My apologies! I'm new to StackExchange and still trying to figure out how everything works. Thank you for the note!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The brackets (`[]`) aren't purely decorative, they specify that you're creating a list.  The `TypeError` you got told you that you're supposed to pass in a single string, not a list of strings.

You probably also don't want the trailing `/` on that path, since it's (hopefully) not part of the actual directory name.  In general you shouldn't hard-code path separators since they aren't OS-portable (that's why `os.path.join` exists).

Give this a try:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Comment: Yes that worked!!!!!! Thank you so much for your help and for your clear explanation!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Really appreciate it :)

Comment: Please don't answer questions where the code is not working as expected on code review. If you answer the question on stackoverflow.com that is fine, but not on code review.